# Different color on Android and iOS using BitmapDescriptor

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I'm using BitmapDescriptor to set color based on status on the map, but there is a difference in Android colors (which are correct) with iOS colors, where on iOS yellow appears as dark green. Any suggestions to make iOS colors like Android colors?

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXR3u.png)
[iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzUjj.jpg)

Here is de color:

```
  _status_icon(status) {
    if (status == "Free") {
      return BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue);
    } else if (status == "Low") {
      return BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen);
    } else if (status == "Moderate") {
      return BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueYellow);
    } else if (status == "Abundant") {
      return BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueOrange);
    } else {
      return BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I just bumped into the same issue, did you ever resolve it?